# Jupyter Notebook hangs when it launched in background. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tmux, ipython, jupyter-notebook

- If it launched in GUI and I left the PC and access it via my notebook, it runs ok.
- If it via launched `jupyter notebook` via SSH, it runs ok. But obviously it will be exited when the SSH is closed.
- If it launched via `jupyter notebook &> /dev/null &` via SSH, it hangs.
- If it launched via `jupyter notebook &` via SSH, it hangs too.

The signs of my Jupyter Notebook hangs:

- It can't be accessed via my laptop browser, always timeout.
- It can't be accessed via lynx on its localhost, always timeout too.
- It can't be killed with `kill $(pgrep jupyter)`, must use SIGKILL (`kill -9 $(pgrep jupyter)`)

Why my Jupyter Notebook hangs when I launched it in background in Linux (Ubuntu)? Other people [seems to have it fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745046/3919805).

How can I launch Jupyter Notebook safely via SSH? Via `tmux`?

Answer (score 0):

Launched by using nohup:

```
$ nohup jupyter notebook
```

After that simply closed terminal to disconnect SSH. To terminated:

```
$ lsof nohup.out
$ kill -9 putPIDhere
```

Saw it in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4PrYQOShnE), which handles with launching an jupyter on an e2 instance.